# Input type date with Y-m-d

Tags: html, date, input

Im using this code at the moment:

```
Deadline: <input type="date" name="deadline" value="<?=$datetime?>">
```

When i echo $datetime it gives: 2015-03-07, but when the script runs the value of the input is 07-03-2015, with other words the data type picks my country use of it, that is dd-mm-yyyy but i want yyyy-mm-dd someone nows how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Comment: Seems you need to share your script where the datetime conversion is happening.

Comment: Try this <?php date('y-m-d') ?>

Answer (score 0):

Use the date function with the desired format and order. You can find out all of the inputs here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp

ex.

echo date("Y/m/d");